# Linux From Scratch: libgmp.la, libmpfr.la, and libmpc.la not found during version-check

Tags: linux, libraries, lfs

I'm trying to build a Linux From Scratch system on my host Linux Mint machine. However, when I run the version-check.sh file, it returns that my system is missing `libgmp.la`, `libmpfr.la`, and `libmpc.la`, even though I have `libgmp10`, `lipmpc3`, and `libmpfr4` . Here is the output of version check:

```
bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release
/bin/sh -> /bin/dash
Binutils: (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.23.52.20130913
bison (GNU Bison) 2.7.12-4996
/usr/bin/yacc -> /usr/bin/bison.yacc
bzip2,  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.
Coreutils:  8.20
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
GNU Awk 4.0.1
/usr/bin/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
(Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.17-93ubuntu4) 2.17
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
gzip 1.6
Linux version 3.11.0-12-generic (buildd@komainu) (gcc version 4.8.1      
(Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu7) ) #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:12:00 UTC 2013
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.16
GNU Make 3.81
GNU patch 2.7.1
Perl version='5.14.2';
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
xz (XZ Utils) 5.1.0alpha
g++ compilation OK
libgmp.la: not found
libmpfr.la: not found
libmpc.la: not found
```

**NOTE:** I'm following version 7.5 of the book and I'm using a 32-bit Linux Mint host (kernel 3.11.0-12).

Comment: Having those packages does not guarantee that those required files are included. Can you use `apt` to check what files those packages include to see if those three files _are_ indeed present on your system?

Comment: On Debian (Mint's ultimate upstream) those are from lib32gmp-dev, lib64gmp-dev, lib32mpfr-dev, etc. Unfortunately Mint is less good about making its packages searchable via the web...

Comment: Have you searched the LFS [support pages](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/support.html)?  This might apply `Note
On some distributions, there have been reports that some libraries used by gcc can be in an inconsistent state and that this interferes with building some LFS packages. To check this, look in /usr/lib and possibly /usr/lib64 for libgmp.la, libmpfr.la, and libmpc.la. Either all three should be present or absent, but not only one or two. If the problem exists on your system, either rename or delete the .la files or install the appropriate missing package.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also trying to build LFS system on my system. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I got the same message during version-check. I went ahead with chapter 5 and during installing gcc, make failed with error. Checking few online help and mailing lists, I found that I had to point to the place where the libraries existed i.e. `/usr/lib` which I found out from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502045/gcc-compilation-cannot-compute-suffix-of-object-files-cannot-compile).

I searched in `/usr/lib` and these libraries did not exist there.
So, I downloaded and installed mpfr, gmp and mpc.
Follow these links: [gmp](https://gmplib.org/), [mpfr](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/#download) and [mpc](http://www.multiprecision.org/index.php?prog=mpc&page=download).

**Note:** follow the build and install [instructions](http://petio.org/tools/gmp.html) given for gmp for mpc and mpfr. using `make check` for gmp results in 1 test failing which I don't think will be a problem here in LFS, hopefully. Example of gmp make check failing 1 test [here](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-bugs/2007-September/000830.html).

Answer (score 3):

This creates a file of installed packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections > package_list

cat package_list | grep ^gcc
-> OK!

cat package_list | grep gmp
-> libgmp10:amd64

cat package_list | grep mpfr
-> libmpfr4:amd64

cat package_list | grep mpc
-> libmpc3:amd64

locate libgmp10
-> /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgmp10:amd64.list

locate libmpfr4
-> /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmpfr4:amd64.list

locate libmpc3
-> /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmpc3:amd64.list

cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgmp10\:amd64.list
-> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.2.0
-> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10

cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmpfr4\:amd64.list
-> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so.4.1.2
-> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so.4

cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmpc3\:amd64.list
-> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpc.so.3.0.0
-> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpc.so.3
```

The requirement for this if used with a 64-bit Architecture and      Debian-Based OS will result in `libgmp.la`, `libmpfr.la`, and `libmpc.la`   being not found. However, a result for the procedures above reveals      that these packages do exist on the system, so one can move forward.

Answer (score 2):

Within Creek's comment to your question lies the answer:
The LFS book (I'm quoting from 7.6) has this to say regarding the three libraries you mention (libgmp.la, libmpfr.la, and libmpc.la):

> "The files identified by this script should be all present or all absent, but not only one or two present."

Which is to say, given your output, you do not need to do anything additional regarding those libraries. That said, I have not completed my LFS install. My answer is only as good as the book. I ended up here myself b/c I had the same question initially.

Answer (score 1):

Download, extract, compile and install the following libraries:

- libgmp.la
- libmpfr.la
- libmpc.la

The general procedure to do it is:

```
tar -xvf lib.name
cd lib.name
./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make
sudo make install
bash library-check.sh
```